# StartService undefined for OnClickListener in fragment

Tags: android, service, listener, fragment

I'm getting this error in a fragment

The method startService(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener

in the onCreateView I have this code

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startService(new Intent(MyService.ACTION1));
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnClickListners don't have a startService method. Try changing it to `FragmentName.getContext().this.startService()`.

Comment: In a fragment so I had to use v.getContext().startService(), but excellent.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your fragment's class name were MyFragment your code will look like

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context ctx = (Context)MyFragment.this.getActivity();
        ctx.startService(new Intent(MyService.ACTION1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
getActivity().startService(new Intent(MyService.ACTION1));
```